# How to find s3 bucket to which cloudfront point?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am curious on how to find the S3 bucket to which cloudfront points (CNAME) E.g: https://drdxyzdg0sjtu.cloudfront.net/ ?

Comment: Is this *your* CloudFront distribution?

Comment: I found it in my browser history. Just wanted to use it as an example if you do not mind.

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to determine the origin server behind a CloudFront distribution that isn't your own.

Additionally, the origin server may not be S3 at all, since CloudFront also supports custom origins.  In this case, at least the root of that distribution appears to be pointing to a bucket, since an S3 error message is returned.

Also, a single CloudFront distribution may have multiple origins, since path pattern matching in each cache behavior can route requests to different origins, including a mix of S3 and custom origins.

Finally, CNAME isn't really a correct term to use, here.  CloudFront supports alternate domain names on the front side and refers to those, parenthenthetically as CNAMEs, and these do not need to match the bucket name when CloudFront is handling the request.  On the back side, when accessing S3, CloudFront appears to use the global endpoint hostname for the bucket, example-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com.  S3 internally maintains the DNS records for that style of URL so that the correct region is reached for each bucket.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to clarify these points to me. Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

When you on your AWS Cloudfront distribution, go on the *Origins* tab, you will find the name of the corresponding S3 bucket under *Origin ID*.